# Compare key and get neatest min key and it's value in JavaScript array of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I have JS object like this

```
    {
        "100": {.. data },
        "200": {.. data },
        "500": {.. data },
        "1000": {.. data }
        /* so on */
    }
```

How to search key with any number like

- if search number is between 0 to 99 then it will return false,
- if search number is between 100 to 199 then it will return key 100 and its value
- if 500 to 999 then return key 500 and its value
- if 1000+ then key as 1000 and its value

here is my code

```
function find(num, obj) 
{
  let keys = Object.keys(obj);
  
  result = keys.concat(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).filter(key => {
     return num <= key;
  }).shift();

  if(result === Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) {
     result = keys.pop();
  }
  return result;
}


console.log( find(125, data) )
```

it's returning 200 instead of 100

Comment: Could you post what have you tried?

Comment: @KaysKadhi updated post with code

Comment: Shouldn't the condition be inverted?   return key<= number  ?

Comment: `return num <= key;` will return where num is less than or equal to key...ie the next key, not the previous one.

Comment: what if you find 300? will the output will be 200 right? since that's the nearest

Comment: also will the key always sorted?

Comment: @VLDCNDN Yes if between 200 to 499 then 200 (key) will be returned

Comment: @VLDCNDN Yes it will be in ASC order.

Comment: @KaysKadhi  if  return key<= number then it will return lowest (0 index) key from array always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach here is to sort the keys in descending order,
then find the first key that target larger than it.

```js
function findNearestMinObj(obj, target) {
  const sortedKeys = Object.keys(obj).map(d => Number(d)).sort((a, b) => b - a)
  const key = sortedKeys.find(k => target >= k)
  if (key === undefined) return false
  return {
    key,
    value: obj[key]
  }
}

const data = {
  100: "one hundred",
  200: "two hundred",
  300: "three hundred",
  400: "four hundred",
  500: "five hundred",
  1000: "one thousand",
}

console.log(`123: ${JSON.stringify(findNearestMinObj(data, 123))}`)
console.log(`456: ${JSON.stringify(findNearestMinObj(data, 456))}`)
console.log(`1234: ${JSON.stringify(findNearestMinObj(data, 1234))}`)
console.log(`99: ${JSON.stringify(findNearestMinObj(data, 99))}`)
console.log(`0: ${JSON.stringify(findNearestMinObj(data, 0))}`)
```